# deserializing JSON from FlickrAPI

Tags: c#, .net, flickr

I am looking for help with some odd behavior re. the Flickr API.
They have a library in .NET, but it does not work with Azure for some reason.
And anyway, the library mightt be overkilll for me.

I just am looking to search by tags and get the first image URL from the results, in C# and not Javascript.
The Flickr call is at: `http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&api_key=[xxx]&tags=[yyy]&safe_search=1&per_page=1`.

I defined a few data classes and get a string back, but JSON.NET and the built in Json.Decode and the DataContractSerializer all don't work for me. I'm clearly doing something wrong.
Does anyone have examples of this working?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Json I have before deserializing is:
{\"photos\":{\"page\":1, \"pages\":481961, \"perpage\":1, \"total\":\"481961\", \"photo\":[{\"id\":\"7803745990\", \"owner\":\"23857115@N08\", \"secret\":\"c5236cc411\", \"server\":\"7109\", \"farm\":8, \"title\":\"Redwood Burns\", \"ispublic\":1, \"isfriend\":0, \"isfamily\":0}]}, \"stat\":\"ok\"}"